# Java arrays: 4-point in a matrix

Tags: java, arrays

Can anyone tell me why in the code below, for array points stands `[k][1]` and no `[k][0]`
It's about drawing a 5-point in a matrix.

```
int w = 20;
int h = 10;
int[][] points = { { 2, 4 }, { 1, 5 }, { 6, 6 }, { 3, 2 }, { 0, 0 } };

for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
        boolean points_exsist = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < points.length; k++) {
            if (points[k][0] == i && points[k][1] == j) {
                points_exsist = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(points_exsist ? "B" : "O");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The question's not clear, plz see [ask].

Comment: This isn't a very good question. For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry this is my first question ever ...